# Why does this php class doesn't work?

Tags: php

i am trying to get this code together but with no luck. Can't figure out what's failing as i am a beginner.

**Trying to:**

Send request to server through SOAP protocol. Previous working code is referred at first.

**What fails?**

I try to make the request and nothing pops out. Nothing good happens. Ran the code on the debugger that did not find anything wrong.

**Previous working code:**

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.pt/xxxxxxx.asmx?WSDL');

$function = 'EditClient';

$arguments= array('EditClient' => array(
                        'empresa'   => 'xxxxx',
                        'password'      => '********',
                        'cliente'        => '19781978',
                        'nome'        => 'Justiceiro',
                        'morada'        => 'Avenida akolá',
                        'localidade'        => 'Integral',
                        'codPostal'        => '4000-100',
                        'pais'        => 'portugal',
                        'telefone'        => '253994257',
                        'fax'        => '000000000',
                        'telemóvel'        => '000000000',
                        'email'        => 'email@email.pt',
                        'nif'        => '000000000',
                        'contacto'        => 'none',
                ));
$options = array('location' => 'http://xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.pt/xxxxxx.asmx?WSDL');

$result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

echo 'Response: ';
print_r($result);
?>
```

**What am i up to**

This is what i've got so far, nothing seems out of place but once again, i am very new at this.

```
<?php

class cliente{

    private $data;
    private $arguments;  
    private $function;  
    private $client;  
    private $result;

    function editcliente(){
        $this->data=array();
        $this->arguments=array();
    }

    public function setData($d){
        $this->data = $d;
    }

    public function validate(){
            $options = array('location' => 'http://xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.pt/xxxxxx.asmx?WSDL');
            $verifica = true;
            foreach ($this->data as $campo) {
                $this->data[$campo] = $_GET[$campo];
                    $arguments = array('EditCliente' => array(
                        'empresa'   => 'xxxxxx',
                        'password'      => '********',
                        'cliente'        => ' ',
                        'nome'        => ''.$this->data["fnome"].'',
                        'morada'        => ''.$this->data["fmorada"].'',
                        'localidade'        => ''.$this->data["flocalidade"].'',
                        'codPostal'        => '4000-100',
                        'pais'        => ''.$this->data["Portugal"].'',
                        'telefone'        => 'vazio',
                        'fax'        => 'vazio',
                        'telemóvel'        => ''.$this->data["ftelemovel"].'',
                        'email'        => ''.$this->data["femail"].'',
                        'nif'        => ''.$this->data["fnif"].'',
                        'contacto'        => ''.$this->data["empresa"].'',
                    ));
                }
            }
    }

    public function getData(){
        print_r($this->data);
        print_r($this->arguments);
    }

    public function sendrequest(){
        $client = new SoapClient('http://apimarvin.ponto25.pt/apimarvin.asmx?WSDL');
        $function = 'EditCliente';
        $result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);
    }   
}

$cliente = new cliente();
$campos = array('fnome','fmorada','flodalidade','fcodigopostal','ftelemovel','femail','fnif','fempresa');

$cliente->setData($campos);
echo ($cliente->validate($data));
echo ($cliente->getData($data));
$cliente->sendrequest($data);

?>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps rephrase your question from `borken. code no work` to `when I do this, I expected this, instead this happens?` or something else equally constructive?

Comment: Thank you, tried to explain what goes on the code. Perhaps you can read now to understand. Thank you once more. Always learning.

Comment: It looks like you aren't informed yet. Time to change that: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: @jonathan thank you for that link, very neat design on that page!!!!. Will read everything.

Comment: Changed the question after reading the ABOUT page

Comment: Is the question better now? What should i improve in order to get ansewer ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I call a SOAP function in PHP

In my index:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8100/PortalService.svc?wsdl');
```

And then:

```
$arguments = array('argument' => $arg);
$response = $wcfclient->NameOfFunction($arguments);
```

Simple and clear.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: I guess that is the procedure, but something is failing in the class itself. I can't figure out what's not compliant with the rules.
Thank you for the cooperation Marijke. Would upvote but can't yet.